# Can we change the UI on Ubuntu on Nexus 7 to make it more touch friendly?

Tags: ubuntu-touch, touchscreen, nexus-7

The UI is not exactly touch friendly in Ubuntu running on the Nexus 7.  The buttons are small, there are only a few multi-touch gestures, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The main purpose of this project is to get the core of Ubuntu ready for mobile devices. This means using RAM and power more efficiently, etc. As of now, we can not change the UI to make it more touch friendly. We will however, happily accept patches.